# How does client can understand that response from server cached by Akamai or not?

Tags: caching, cookies, cdn, akamai

I am afraid that `Akamai` can cache cookie. I want to avoid it.

Is there way to check it?

Can I I open browser, browser console and detect it?

P.S. I have not direct access to akamai configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a addon called "Akamai Content Source" which is provided in akamai portal. "Content Source is a Mozilla Firefox and Firebug Extension that gives an overview of cache information in Firebug's Content Source panel. Both Firefox and Firebug are required to use this add-on." This will tell you if the request was served from akamai or it went to origin to get the response.

Comment: Also if you believe akamai is caching your cookie information etc. then i suggest contact akamai support, they will be able to check and help you with your configuration.